# SetTemplate on specific pages for logged in customers?

Tags: magento

I've got an issue with Magento xml layouts. I've been trying to change the page template when a customer is logged in, but only for specific pages in the layout. I've tried using the `<customer_logged_in>` handle in my xml but I can't get it to reference another handle specifically.

Non-working example of what I'd like it to do:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.html</template></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.html</template></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_out>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Is this possible to accomplish with the XML layout system or should I be looking at another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately with Magento layouts, there is no way to filter between two layout handles.

What I would recommend is slightly different and more complex, but I believe that it will give you the flexibility that you need.

**You will need to create a module to do this.** I am including all code necessary to do this.

#### Module Definition:

`app/etc/Your_Module.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

#### Config XML:

`app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <Your_Module>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </Your_Module>
        </modules>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
            <observers>
                <your_module_name>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Your_Module/Observer</class>
                    <method> controllerActionLayoutGenerateBlocksAfter</method>
                </your_module_name>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

#### The code that makes it work

Then at this path `app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Observer.php`:

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionLayoutGenerateBlocksAfter ($observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getAction();

        if ($controller->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
            $layout = $controller->getLayout();
            $rootBlock = $layout->getBlock('root');

            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $rootBlock->setTemplate('page/1-column.html');
            } else {
                $rootBlock->setTemplate('page/2-columns.html');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I took a few tips from: [update layout programatically in magento event observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458611/update-layout-programatically-in-magento-event-observer))