# How to inject pure javascript into head in Magento 1.9 extension?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm developing a Magento extension that deals with analytics. One of the things it needs to do is pass events (such as `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` and `catalog_controller_product_view`) from the backend PHP observer class to the frontend javascript.

I have the events working in myextension's config.xml:

```
     <events>
        ...
        <catalog_controller_product_view>
            <observers>
                <myextension>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>myextension/observer</class>
                    <method>productViewContent</method>
                </myextension>
            </observers>
        </catalog_controller_product_view>
        <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
            <observers>
                <myextension>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>myextension/observer</class>
                    <method>productAddToCart</method>
                </myextension>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
        ...
    </events>
```

I have the Observer.php model implemented to write to the log currently:

```
public function productViewContent($observer) {

    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    Mage::log('('.$product->getId() .') '. $product->getName().' has been viewed.', null, 'product.log');        
}

public function productAddToCart($observer) {

    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    Mage::log('('.$product->getId() .') '. $product->getName().' has been added to cart.', null, 'product.log');
}
```

and I'm seeing the correct product details in the product.log.

Now where I am stuck is in this class:

```
class Mynamespace_Myextension_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head {
      // some session code here
      $this->addJs('myextension/file.js');
}
```

I've successfully detected that myextension/file.js is loading, but I need to be able to pass dynamic event info to the JS file. I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```
class Mynamespace_Myextension_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head {
      // some session code here
      $this->addRawHTML('<script>var myevent='addtocart';var myproduct=$product_id</script>');
      $this->addJs('myextension/file.js');
}
```

...so that myevent and myproduct are available to the code that runs in file.js. Obviously there is no such method `addRawHTML`.

Hopefully that makes sense. I tried

```
echo "<script>alert('add_to_cart');</script>";
```

in the my extension's Head.php block and I get the alert as expected, but it of course is printed before the first line of the html which is not the correct way to do it.

Also, I am currently using the session to write details about the event from the Observer so that the _prepareLayout method in Mynamespace_Myextension_Block_Html_Head can read them and forward them on to the JS in the layout. Is there a better way?

In a nutshell, I'm not able to modify layout.xml/theme.xml because this is an extension, and I'm not able to use addJs alone because I need the JS file to be dynamically generated or detect JS variables written dynamically into the page.

Is it considered bad practice to call add JS with a PHP file?

```
$this->addJs('myextension/file.php?myevent=add_to_cart&product_id='.$product_id);
```

and render the JS file dynamically using PHP? That might work but it seems like a hack.

Thanks for your advice.

**UPDATE:** I have managed to get something working, but in a "non-magento-way".  I followed something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12465806/203118), basically generating Javascript on the fly from the observer directly:

```
public function generateLayout($observer)
{
    // I do this if there's an event in a custom session variable
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    $headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
    $block = $layout->getBlock('head');
    $block->setText("
    <script>
    var myevent = '$event';
    var myproduct = '$product';
    </script>
    ");
    $headBlock->append($block);
}
```

I would still like to approach it properly using Magento best practice.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, Magento uses a javascript variable `var spConfig` (in view pages) for storing product data to be used in javascript for changing prices and other thigs.

Can't you use such a js variables that store product/cart info and use them in js file that you are including (that is file.js)

Comment: I wasn't aware of spConfig. I'll read up on it and let you know, thanks Anil!

Comment: I can use spConfig for some of the information needed for analytics (eg product sku and price of the viewed product) but I am still looking for the best "Magento-friendly" way to include dynamic Javascript in the head of magento layout. I've updated the question with a working solution but it is injecting JS code into the layout directly from the Observer. While that works, I believe there is a better Magento-best-practice way to do it.